# What's definition $(\ker \varphi)_P$ the stalk of kernel presheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

If $\varphi : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ a morphism of sheaves then what definition of $(\ker \varphi)_P$? I digested that an element is $\langle U,r \rangle $ where $r \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ and $\varphi(U)(r) = 0$ and pairs are identified as in usual identifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf on any topological space $X$ (which I assume is what you're interested in here), the stalk of $\mathscr{F}$ at a point $x\in X$ is $\mathscr{F}_x:=\varinjlim_{x\in U}\mathscr{F}(U)$, the direct limit over the sets $\mathscr{F}(U)$ over all open sets $U\subseteq X$ containing $x$. So, an element of this set is an equivalence class of a pair $(s,U)$ where $x\in U\subseteq X$ is open and $s\in\mathscr{F}(U)$, and this equals the class represented by $(s^\prime,V)$ if and only if there is an open $W\subseteq U\cap V$ and a section $t\in\mathscr{F}(W)$ such that $s\vert_W=t=s^\prime\vert_W$.

In particular, for a morphism $\varphi:\mathscr{F}\rightarrow\mathscr{G}$, the sheaf kernel $\ker\varphi$ is defined by $(\ker\varphi)(U)=\ker(\varphi(U))$, where $\varphi(U):\mathscr{F}(U)\rightarrow\mathscr{G}(U)$ is the map of sections over $U$. So, as you say, an element of $(\ker\varphi)_x$ is specified by an open set $x\in U\subseteq X$ and a section $s\in\ker(\varphi(U))$.

EDIT: The answer to the question posed in the comments is yes. Even though the image presheaf $U\mapsto\mathrm{im}(\varphi(U))$ is not generally a sheaf, the natural map from this presheaf to its sheafification (which is by definition the image sheaf) induces isomorphisms on stalks, so the stalk of the image sheaf is the same as the stalk of the image presheaf, which is $\varinjlim_{x\in U}\mathrm{im}(\varphi(U))$, and so an element of this stalk is represented by a pair $(t,U)$ where $t=\varphi(U)(s)$ for some $s\in\mathscr{F}(U)$.

Moreover, one has $\mathrm{im}(\varphi)_x=\mathrm{im}(\varphi_x)$ via the stalk at $x$ of the canonical map $\mathrm{im}(\varphi)\rightarrow\mathscr{G}$, and similarly $\ker(\varphi)_x=\ker(\varphi_x)$ under the stalk at $x$ of the canonical inclusion $\ker(\varphi)\rightarrow\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: Thank you Keenan. I have also other doubt in my mind is true that $(\text{Im} \varphi)_P$ has any element $\langle U,t \rangle$ where $t = \varphi(s)$ for some $s \in \mathcal{F}(V)$?

Comment: I see edit thank you. I read Hartshorne he never define what is  surjective map of sheaves $\varphi : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$.  Surjective means sheafification of image presheaf equals $\mathcal{G}$?.

Comment: Given a morphism $\varphi:\mathscr{F}\rightarrow\mathscr{G}$, the construction of the image sheaf (which as you say is the sheafification of the image presheaf) yields a canonical map $\mathrm{im}(\varphi)\rightarrow\mathscr{G}$. We say $\varphi$ is surjective if this map is an isomorphism. It is equivalent that $\varphi_x$ be surjective for each $x\in X$, or that for each open subset $U$ of $X$ and each $t\in\mathscr{G}(U)$, there exist an open covering $U=\bigcup_i U_i$ and sections $s_i\in\mathscr{F}(U_i)$ such that $\varphi(U_i)(s_i)=t\vert_{U_i}$. Surjectivity does not imply that

Comment: $\varphi(U)$ is surjective for each open set $U$. In any case I'm pretty sure Hartshorne defines this somewhere, or at least gives an exercise about it (he might call it an epimorphism).

Comment: I understand not last two lines. From what I wrote in my question, isn't it clear $\ker (\varphi_x) = (\ker \varphi)_x$ and same for image?

Comment: Dear @Kyle, No, it's not clear. For example one needs to use the fact that direct limits are exact. Both statements require an argument.

Answer (score 2):

From your title I guess you know that $U\mapsto \ker\phi(U)$ is a presheaf (it is in fact a sheaf). We call "$\ker\phi$" this presheaf. As such, it has stalks at every point:
$$
(\ker\phi)_P:=\varinjlim_{U\ni P}\ker\phi(U),
$$
and one can show that $(\ker\phi)_P=\ker \phi_P$, where $\phi_P$ is the map on stalks $\mathcal F_P\to\mathcal G_P$ induced by $\phi$.